# document.getElementById( ).value não está funcionando com window.open( )

Tags: javascript, html5

Quero gerar uma página de impressão limpinha com algumas informações apenas. Para isso estou utilizando o seguinte código (bem resumido) em javascript:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myWindow = window.open(" ", "_self");
  var str1 = "Janela de Impressão";
  var result1 = str1.fontsize(5);
  myWindow.document.write("<strong><center>", result1, "</center></strong>");
  var str2 = "Dados da Impressão";
  var result2 = str2.fontsize(5);
  myWindow.document.write("<strong><br><br>", result2, "</strong>");
  var salario_bruto = document.getElementById("salario").value;
  myWindow.document.write("<strong><br>Salário: </strong>");
  myWindow.document.write(salario_bruto);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Salário: <input id="salario" name="salario" type="text">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Imprimir</button>
</div>
```

Eu testei isso offline e funcionou perfeitamente. Porém quando eu subi pro site eu clico em "imprimir" e não repassa o valor do salário. Alguma ideia? Valeu.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você está mudando de janela antes de pegar o valor do elemento. Apenas pegue o valor antes de dar o `window.open`:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var salario_bruto = document.getElementById("salario").value;
  var myWindow = window.open(" ", "_self");
  var str1 = "Janela de Impressão";
  var result1 = str1.fontsize(5);
  myWindow.document.write("<strong><center>", result1, "</center></strong>");
  var str2 = "Dados da Impressão";
  var result2 = str2.fontsize(5);
  myWindow.document.write("<strong><br><br>", result2, "</strong>");
  myWindow.document.write("<strong><br>Salário: </strong>");
  myWindow.document.write(salario_bruto);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Salário: <input id="salario" name="salario" type="text">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Imprimir</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sam não tinha visto que você tinha respondido, foi mal

Comment: Tranquilo! Foi por alguns segundos. Boa resposta!

Comment: Poutz, que vacilo o meu! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Bruno não deixe de marcar a resposta com ✔. Abs!

Answer (score 3):

Após abrir a janela usando `_self`, o código não acha mais o id `salario` da página porque a página é substituída. Coloque a linha que pega o id do input antes de abrir a janela na função:

```
function myFunction() {
    var salario_bruto = document.getElementById("salario").value; //<< AQUI
    var myWindow = window.open(" ", "_self");
    var str1 = "Janela de Impressão";
    var result1 = str1.fontsize(5);
    myWindow.document.write("<strong><center>",result1, "</center></strong>");
    var str2 = "Dados da Impressão";
    var result2 = str2.fontsize(5);
    myWindow.document.write("<strong><br><br>",result2, "</strong>");
    myWindow.document.write("<strong><br>Salário: </strong>"); myWindow.document.write(salario_bruto);
}
```